# query in visual basic 6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have data like this

```
TrNo | LAR | Model   | Transport

001    S001  P-123     30000    --> this one for new field jasa
001    S001  Service   15000    --> this one for new field transport
002    S002  ABC-34    30000
003    S003  SA567     30000
003    S003  Service   15000
```

And I want this table become

```
TrNo   | LAR  | Model |  Jasa   | Transport

001      S001   P-123   30000     15000
002      S002   ABC-34  30000       -
003      S003   SA567   30000     15000
```

Please help me...

And I used code like this

> strSql1 = SELECT DISCTINCT TrNo, LAR, Model Transport from Tbl_Claim WHERE Model like '" & service &"'

And

> strSql2 = SELECT DISTINCT TrNo, LAR, Model, Transport, strSql1.Transport from Tbl_Claim LEFT JOIN strSql1 ON Tbl_Claim.TrNo = strSql1.TrNo WHERE Tbl_Claim.Model Not like '" & service & "'

Comment: If you are using ADO object you should use % in your like ...WHERE Model like '%" & service & "%'" for DAO I believe you need to use * instead of %? Although Its already more than 2 decades now since I last use DAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
SELECT TC.TrNo, TC.LAR, TC.Model, TC.Transport AS Jasa, TP.Transport FROM tbl_claim TC
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TrNo,Transport FROM tbl_Claim WHERE Model='Service') TP
ON TP.TrNo=TC.TrNo
WHERE TC.Model!='Service' ORDER BY TC.TrNo;
```